# Does Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) supports STS'es based on WS-Trust

Tags: wif, sts-securitytokenservice, ws-federation, ws-trust

Our partner is trying to setup a [PicketLink STS](http://www.jboss.org/picketlink/Fed.html) which according to spec is based on WS-Trust. I can't find any information whether or not WIF is supporting this. I know it supports WS-Federation which is an extension on WS-Trust. Most of the time both terms are used in conjunction so I don't know if WS-Trust alone is supported as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, WIF supports WS-Trust. The docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748475.aspx

It'd help if you explained the scenario a little bit more. Are you building a website? Are you trying to authenticate users on "PicketLink".

`WS-Trust` is generally used for "rich clients" (used for "active federation"). `WS-Federation` (and `SAML 2.0`) are typically used for web sites (used for "passive federation").

WIF can do `WS-Trust` and `WS-Federation`. It can't do SAML (the protocol). Confusion is often augmented by the fact that people use the word `SAML` to refer both to the protocol and the token format. WS-Federation uses SAML *tokens*. WIF understands **SAML Tokens**.

Comment: It seems only active STS is supported by WS-Trust. Bummer I needed passive STS support.

Comment: Could you not go WS-Fed (passive) via WIF to ADFS via active to PicketLink?

Comment: @nzpcmad We are exploring the possibilities right now, maybe ADFS is the way to go but that choice is not mine to make.